# Adding generic button click sound

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm creating a game app in android studio and need to add a generic click sound when any button is pressed on screen. I figure I can do this a couple different ways, someone said I should use this code

```
view.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

But I am having trouble implementing this because it seems to only work in onTouchListener when I need it for onClickListener... So, my next idea is a can create a MediaPlayer object, and with that object add a resource from the raw directory, with a 1 second audio clip of a click sound (but I don't know where to find this sound). I would then set this MediaPlayer object to play whenever a button is clicked. How can I get this click sound to play when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to use Audiomanager to play the sound. Follow the below steps:

define an AudioManager in the Activity class

```
AudioManager audioManager;
```

Initialise in onCreate.

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

In the click method, use the audioManager to play the sound.

```
public void play(View view) {
    audioManager.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK,1.0f);
}
```

Note that the volume is given as `1.0f` if you don't specify the volume, you won't hear any sound. Hope this helps!